# how to allow non-alphabatic character in validation

Tags: php, cakephp

how can i allow non-alphabatic character like ,.':;" using regex in my cakephp project
my code:

```
'alpha' => array(
    'rule' => '/^[a-z\s\-\']+$/i',
    'message' => 'Please limit to alphabetical and non-alphabetical characters.'
    );
```

Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried including them in your character class (i.e. between the square brackets of your rule)?

Comment: You already have non-word characters being matched in that regex. Along with `a-z` you allow also whitespace, the dash character `-` and a single quote character `'`... Your message also doesn't make too much sense `"limit to alphabetical and non-alphabetical"`...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your rule already allows certain non-alphabetic characters. It allows a whitespace character (space character), a hyphen (dash character) and an apostrophe (single quote character).  All you'll have to do is add to the list :

```
'alpha' => array(
    'rule' => '/^[a-z\s\-\'\.,:;]+$/i',
    'message' => 'Please limit to alphabetical and non-alphabetical characters.'
);
```

Don't forget to escape the characters with special meanings such as the period character `.`.

Be aware that this rule is quite relaxed. It will allow all sorts of non regular inputs such as -

- `;;;;;;;;`
- `--;;--::`
- `''.  .''`

Comment: how to allow all spacial characters? @Lix

Comment: I need to allow this <>?{}[]!@#$%^&* characters @Lix

Comment: @sha - all you'll have to do is add them to the regular expression inthe same way I added the other characters... Don't forget to escape the ones that have special meanings with regard to regex... `?[]!$^*` all have special meanings, so you'll have to add a slash before them to escape the character telling the regex engine to search for that exact character an not it's alternative meaning. For example, the `$` sign actually means the end of the string... But if you are searching for the dollar character itself, you'll have to write `\$`.

Comment: Notice also that your question has now changed substantially from your original one. Perhaps you should update your original post with all the details you need....